# How to pronunce some words

Tags: pronunciation

How would one pronounce the following words?

1. Poie
2. Poc
3. Poce

These are not real words.

Comment: You do realize that, for English, [pronounciation can be ambiguous](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghoti)? To me, this question is somewhat pointles until you explain *why* you are asking, especially because I wonder how other learners would benefit fom an attempted answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it even says in the question that they aren't real words.

Comment: Don't understand the negative reaction to this question-- OP clearly is trying to learn general principles for English reading, which, though riddled with exceptions, certainly exist. The answer to the question: (1) doesn't look like an English word enough for me to guess. (2) would almost certainly be pronounced to rhyme with rock, and (3) would rhyme with "dose."

Answer (score 3):

There is no valid answer if these aren't real words. In English, there aren't hard and fast **rules** for how something should be pronounced. Consider these words:

> Though
>
> Through
>
> Cough
>
> Tough

These words look like they should be pronounced similarly, but every single word is different. Thoe, Throo, Cof and Tuff. Now, I could guess at the pronunciation, but there's no way to know if I'm right. Consider the word "yacht". If you didn't know the word, what would you guess? How about Acai? Paradigm? I guarantee that you would guess all of these words wrong, and so would I.

By the way, if you want to know the pronunciations, they are "yot", "uh-sie-ee" and "pair-uh-dime".